# Unable to get Wordpress up and running

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, iis-7

I am trying to get Wordpress up and running and have run into a problem with the login mechanism. When I ran the Wordpress setup for the first time it successfully created the database and filled the `wp_capabilities` table, but it failed to create the user. I did some research and found how the user data is stored, and created the entries manually. It is letting me log in but then gives me the following error:

`You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.`

I added the following keys in `wp_usermeta`:

```
wp_capabilities = a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
wp_user_level = 10
```

Any idea what is wrong? If it makes any difference I am running this on Windows IIS7 (with PHP support).

Comment: what's in your wp-config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you start again from scratch and ensure that the database user you configure in `wp-config.php` has the correct write permissions for the database. Also I would suggest changing the permissions of the wordpress directory to read, write, execute for all users while you are setting it up then change `group` and `other` permissions to read and execute only, after set up.

For windows you will want something like:

```
CACLS <your_wordpress_directory> /E /T /C "<user>":F
```

to grant full permissions. Then:

```
CACLS <your_wordpress_directory> /E /T /C /W "<user>"
```

to revoke write permissions.

**EDITS:**

If you are seeing SMTP failure issues have a look [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/873098-iis7-and-smtp-email-issues/) to see if disabling authentication as a requirement helps.

Comment: I have isolated the problem to step 2 of the installer. It is trying to send an email and crashing due to the fact that I don't have an SMTP server with no authentication that I can use. My only options now is to either find an SMTP server without authentication or stop it from sending the email.

Comment: Yes IIS7. I don't know for sure why it is hanging on step 2 but a user had a similar problem and it was the mail function for him.

Comment: Have a look at the link in my edits... That should help you. If you have SMTP authentication turned on without it being set up correctly then you could well see the error you describe.

Comment: I set up SMTP for IIS7 using correct details and it is still getting stuck on page 2. [This](http://i.imgur.com/CJybO.jpg) is what I see.

Comment: Hmm curious. Can I assume you are not blocking the SMTP port on your machine, router or external firewall? Can you post the exception you are seeing?

Comment: I don't know what the exception was as it was running without error logging, but I don't really care. I only wanted to get WordPress running so I could look at some rendered HTML elements, but I managed to find a website that has what I want. I will mark you as answer.